# Where to keep resource file in asp.net mvc application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, resources, multilingual

I am working on a MVC Application, which has WCF as back end. 
I have all POCOs in my Data Entities CS project, which is shared between WCF and Web application projects. Now, I have a scenario, where I need to convert an MVC application to multilingual.
I have created one resource project, and given reference of it to both Entities project (to use display attributes) and Web.

But it copies the Resource dll to WCF as well, which I feel is wrong.

So, where can I put my resource files?

If in Web, then how to use Data Annotation attributes?

I am using Display attributes on Enums, instead of description to display it in multilingual form. So again, where should these Enums be (I kept them in Entities)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a reference to your project. Try adding just a reference to the DLL within the bin folder of the project your trying to share. That way when you reference from 2 projects, each project points to just that one dll. In production you should setup a folder parent of your root web directory that contains those "shared" DLLs.

Comment: But i am using Resource Class in Entities project, so i need a reference of resource in Entity. If i refer resource in Entity its dll will be copied to WCF where it is not required at all. That is my concern

Comment: You will have to write or generate ViewModels to annotate your entities.